# Please remove this problem:: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

`root cause`

java.lang.Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: '\usr\crt\Documentum' is an invalid value for the property dfc.data.dir
    com.documentum.fc.client.DfClientSupport.<init>(DfClientSupport.java:115)
    com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.<init>(DfClient.java:32)
    com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.getLocalClientEx(DfClient.java:71)
    com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.getLocalClient(DfClient.java:57)
    itgi.hcl.help.SearchDocument.<init>(SearchDocument.java:42)
    itgi.hcl.action.PolicySearchAction.searchDocumentum(PolicySearchAction.java:271)
    itgi.hcl.action.PolicySearchAction.execute(PolicySearchAction.java:58)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the`Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 logs`.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat wild guess that you're running this on a Linux box and someone has attempted to use a path name having backslashes (`\`) as file separator character.  Try `/usr/crt/Documentum` instead.   That and give us a few more clues.